# Is J2 is eligible to renew visa when J1 visa stamp expired but maintaining J1 status?

Tags: usa, visa, j-visa

I have faced confusion on J2 visa renewal. My wife maintaining J1 status in US but her J1 visa is expired and so mine too. Now I am outside of US and want to renew my J2 visa. But the embassy of US at Belgium says, I'm no longer eligible for J2 visa as associated J1 visa has been expired, though she is maintaining her J1 status in USA. They said that the only way I could have a J2 now if my wife renew her J1 visa stamp by traveling outside USA and get new J1 visa.
But looking in blogs and also the person responsible officer of my wife says this supposed not to be like this. Anyone face the same problem, and how to resolve this issue.

Comment: For what it's worth, they may be misinterpreting the Foreign Affairs Manual at [9 FAM 402.5-6(I)(7)](https://fam.state.gov/fam/09FAM/09FAM040205.html#M402_5_6_I_7), which I think intends to say that J-2 visas are subject to the same validity rules as apply to the principal J-1 visa, but could be read as saying that a J-2 visa must be limited to the actual validity period of the principal's actual visa.  Have you asked to speak with a supervisor?